# Insert newly created id value into the column of another table as Foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone PHP and mysql noob here

I'm creating a form to 
create a new user 
and at the same time add a contact
but  **user** and **contact** are in two different table

and i need the newly **user_ID** to reference the **user_ID**(FK) in the **tbl_contact**

how would i do it?

Comment: First create your user, retrieve the user_ID and then create the contact. This is also a case where a transaction would make sense:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all insert the user

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_user (...) VALUES (...)");
```

then retrieve the last inserted id

```
$LIid=mysql_insert_id();
```

then insert the contact with this id

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_contact (user_ID,...) VALUES ($LIid,...)");
```

[Refrence](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

If you want to use mysqli

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tbl_user (...) VALUES (...)");
$LIid=$mysqli->insert_id;
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tbl_contact (user_ID,...) VALUES ($LIid,...)");
```

Comment: Avoid using the deprecated mysql functions, switch to mysqli or PDO.